# Google Places API gives name of the state as city in the suggestion

Tags: web-services, google-places-api, google-places, react-google-places-autocomplete

We are using google places API to autocomplete state, city or region searches. The issue is when one searches for a state, Places API gives two results one for the state and the other for the city/region. For eg, if we search Maine we get Maine, USA and Maine, ME, USA both in the response. Would anyone please provide a way to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use "types" parameter?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#types
"cities" type might give the result you want.